# How can i enter the dates from this form into a certain table in the connected database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

This is my input form:

```
<form id='vnos-form' action="/dijagnoza" method="POST"> 
          <label for="zacetek">Datum začetka:*</label>
          <input  type="date" id="zacetek" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="zacetek" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="konec">Datum konca (če boleznik ozdravil): </label>
          <input type="date" id="konec" class="form-control" placeholder="Vnesi datum konca" name="konec">
        </div>
        <label>Opis poteka:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="opispoteka"></textarea>
        </div>
</form>
```

I want to input the zacetek and konec dates into this bolezni table from my database. Here is the table:

```
Table: bolezni
Columns:
idBolezni int AI PK 
PotrjenaDijagnoza tinyint 
Datum_Zacetka date 
Datum_Konca date 
Uporabnik_idUporabnik int 
Dijagnoza_idDijagnoza int 
Simptomi_id_Simptomi int
```

These are parts of the code in a bigger project, so I already have an app.js file and a separate connection.js file for connecting to the database.

Can anyone help me with what I should write in the backend? I've tried several things but none work.

Comment: Can you show us the _several things_ that you have tried?

Comment: var sql = "INSERT INTO bolezni (PotrjenaDijagnoza, Datum_Zacetka, Datum_Konca) VALUES ('"true"', '"+req.body.zacetka+"', '"+req.body.konca"')";
  db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");